# How do I generate a number for a lottery and later proves its existence

Tags: encryption, commitments

I want to create a lottery that works like this: I choose a secret number A in the range [0:999] and publish an object B. People must try to guess the number A to win. When somebody wins, I want to publish an object C. The object C shall now together with B prove the existence of A, such that people know that A was determined from the beginning of the lottery.

Calculating A given B should be either impossible or unfeasible due to computational requirements.

I don't know much about cryptography, but have come up with the following proposal on my own:

```
p1, p2 = large prime numbers chosen at random, where p1 < p2   
f = a hash function: N x N -> {0, 1, ..., 1000}

A = f(p1 | p2)
B = (p1*p2, f)
C = p1
```

My idea is that given B, it is easy to calculate A if C is also known, but computationally hard without C. Note that both the hash function and the product of p1 and p2 is given as the object B.

What do you think about my proposal, will it work? Is there any better or simpler methods?

Comment: Sounds like you need some kind of [commitment scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commitment_scheme). Whereby you can publish (commit to) a value (your lottery number) that you can later reveal, with the restriction that the receivers can verify that it was not changed between commitment and reveal, but are also unable to determine the original value prior to the reveal. Another example protocol is available [here](http://www.cs.mcgill.ca/~crepeau/CRYPTO/BCDemo/BCprotocol.html).

Comment: @Iridium thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: http://eprint.iacr.org/2011/223.pdf $\;$

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use [HMAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash-based_message_authentication_code) for this. HMAC is available in pretty much every crypto library out there.

The process would work like this. Randomly pick A and C. For simplicity, let's assume they are strings (of any length). Compute $B=HMAC(A,C)$. Publish $B$. Once someone guesses $A$, you publish $C$. Anyone can then verify that $B=HMAC(A,C)$.

As long as a good hash function is used, and $C$ is sufficiently long (say 128 bits), knowing $B$ should not help anyone compute $A$.

---

The benefits of doing this over what you propose in the question is that it is much simpler, faster, and the values generated are much smaller. For factorization to be hard enough, your primes will have to be around 1000 bits each.

Comment: The drawback "of doing this over" a perfectly binding scheme is that, for each hash function, there exists a fast way to break the binding property.

Comment: Uhm, how do you break the binding property of an actual hash function "fast", e.g. SHA256? I mean, for that you would have to break at least collision resistance.

Comment: @tylo : $\:$ One uses a short collision in the actual hash function. $\;\;\;\;$

Comment: What do you mean by short collision? A partial collision? That's not gonna help in this case. If you can break collision resistance of HMAC, then this is broken, yes. This isnt perfectly binding, I know, but unless you can break collision resistance, hash functions (or something like HMAC) are computationally binding for everyone.

Comment: @tylo : $\:$ I mean a collision with short inputs. $\;\;\;\;$

Comment: I ended up using this approach with the SHA512 hash function. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

There is one subtle problem with your proposed protocol: unless $f$ is restricted to commutative functions, the lottery can choose to reveal one of two values.

Here's how he does it: the lottery selects $p1$ and $p2$ as per the protocol, and publishes $p1\times p2, f$.  However, when it comes time to reveal the committed value, and the lottery sees that the answer $f(p1, p2)$ would cause a large payout, he can choose to reveal the value $C=p2$.  This value would validate, and the alternative revealed answer $f(p2, p1)$ may be more to the lottery's liking.

Now, as mikeazo has stated, this is actually a fairly well-studied problem in crypto; see his answer for an easier (and more secure) solution.

Comment: Good point. I thought of overcoming this by stating that p1 is always the smallest prime.

Comment: @KentMuntheCaspersen: I missed where you said that

Comment: I didn't. I have just updated question accordingly

Answer (score 1):

Nice question, however, you could have objects $C_{0}\dots C_{999}$ that you could still use to select a winner if you have an inversion of the algorithm, or just plenty of time before the lottery starts.

You likely need a referee, or input from the participants from the lottery. A scheme could be that organizer selects (single use) public/private key pair and tells public key. He must encode a public random string (provided by participants?) and publish the result. Then he must publish the result of encoding the secret number. After the lottery, he can show that the both the secret number and random string provide the published results.

Comment: I don't think I could have any other C objects. Since B is already published, C must be one of the prime factors of B (only 2 exists, p1 and p2).

Comment: Who chooses/knows p1 and p2? Suppose only you need tell p2, with sufficient time, you could find 1000 versions of p1 for each desired outcome. And if you need to publish p1 and p2, participants could determine the winning ticket from the published outcome.

Comment: I choose p1 and p2, but publish only the value B = (p1*p2). Only after a winner is found, I publish C=p1. As I understand, no efficient algorithm for prime factorization exists, which is needed to factor B into (p1,p2) used as input to the hash function f that produces A.

Comment: If you may choose p1 and p2, with sufficient preparation time, you could still seriously influence the outcome.

Comment: Nevermind, I think you're right on the factorization. Have to do some thinking, but have to leave for dinner too..

Comment: You are right that I can choose p1 and p2 so that A becomes any number I want it to be in the range [0:999]. That is not a problem. I only need people to know that if they pay for a ticket, they have a genuine 1/1000 chance of winning. They must be sure that I cannot just change the number A if they guess it right. This is because if I change A, then I cannot afterwards provide a C that satisfy the given conditions.